# I got this error "An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/register.jsp at line 35"

Tags: java, jsp, hql

I'm confused about my code I already change everything but still doesn't work and this is my error message : org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/register.jsp

```
          class="col-xs-2 control-label">Username</label>
   <div class="col-xs-3">
   <p class="help-block" style="color: red;"><form:errors path="userName"/></p>
            <form:input cssClass="form-control" path="userName" id="userName"/>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What's the exception, and which line is #35?

Comment: Is there actually a file /WEB-INF/jsp/register.jsp?  I didn't think that you could put JSP files in the WEB-INF directory.  Look in the log file for the server.  You may find more information there.  Try moving /WEB-INF/jsp/register.jsp to /jsp/register.php.

Comment: try to move your "register.jsp" from web-inf and put it in the web-content cause the web-inf is a secured folder where you can not run jsp files

Comment: Bradley Ross : I use Eclipse

Comment: @PacMan : the problem in here line 35 <form:input cssClass="form-control" path="userName" id="userName"/>

Comment: Post the full stack trace.  Did you import the spring form library? `<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>`

Comment: @bphilipnyc problem solved thanks m8